# Android Studio notification

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications, countdowntimer

I have a problem with a notification that I want to show what is intended is that if the counter reaches 0 it then gives me a notification that the time is up, but if it is okay everything is fine but I do not get a notification if time is up can someone help with this? Thanks in advance! Below this text you can find the code that I get stuck on.

```
package com.example.melkanalysetimer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class wit extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView countdownText;
    private Button countdownButton;
    private Button krat;
    private Button remove;
    private TextView scoreb;
    private TextView money;
    private TextView reset;

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private long timeLeftInMilliseconds = 960000;
    private boolean timerRunning;
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 960000;

    int score = 0;
    double geld = 0.00;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wit);

        countdownText = findViewById(R.id.countdown_text);
        countdownButton = findViewById(R.id.countdown_button);
        krat = findViewById(R.id.b_add);
        scoreb = findViewById(R.id.tv_score);
        remove = findViewById(R.id.b_remove);
        money = findViewById(R.id.ssgeld);
        reset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        scoreb.setText("Kratjes: "+ score);
        money.setText("Geld: "+ geld);

        krat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                score++;
                scoreb.setText("Kratjes: "+ score);
                geld = geld + 1.5;
                money.setText("Geld: "+ geld);
            }
        });

        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(score >= 1){
                    score--;
                }
                scoreb.setText("Kratjes: "+ score);
                if(geld >= 1.5){
                    geld = geld - 1.5;
                }
                money.setText("Geld: "+ geld);
            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });

        countdownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startStop();
            }
        });

        updateTimer();
    }

    public void startStop() {
        if (timerRunning) {
            stopTimer();
        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                timeLeftInMilliseconds = l;
                updateTimer();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                addNotification();
            }

        }.start();

        countdownButton.setText("PAUZE");
        timerRunning = true;
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countdownButton.setText("START");
        timerRunning = false;
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        timeLeftInMilliseconds = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateTimer();
    }

    public void addNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle("TEST!!")
                .setContentText("TEST!");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, wit.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    public void updateTimer() {
        int minutes = (int) timeLeftInMilliseconds / 60000;
        int seconds = (int) timeLeftInMilliseconds % 60000 / 1000;

        String timeLeftText;

        timeLeftText = "" + minutes;
        timeLeftText += ":";
        if (seconds < 10) timeLeftText += "0";
        timeLeftText += seconds;

        countdownText.setText(timeLeftText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this code this missing handling channels on newer android version
you need to add channels starting android o
here is an example of a working code in kotlin adding a max priority channel

```
     override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val channels = ArrayList<NotificationChannel>(2)
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id),
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            ).apply {
                description = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
            }
            val channelHigh = NotificationChannel(
                getString(R.string.HIGH_notification_channel_id),
                getString(R.string.HIGH_notification_channel_id),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                description = getString(R.string.HIGH_notification_channel_id)
            }

            channels.add(channel)
            channels.add(channelHigh)
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannels(channels)
        }


        // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
        val resultIntent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)
        // Create the TaskStackBuilder
        val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = 
             TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
            // Add the intent, which inflates the back stack
            addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent)
            // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
            getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            if (!it.channelId.isNullOrEmpty()) it.channelId!! else
                getString(R.string.HIGH_notification_channel_id)
        )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(if (it.title.isNullOrEmpty()) 
            getString(R.string.app_name) else it.title)
            .setContentText(it.body)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .
            setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)

        if (it.imageUrl != null) {
            val bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(it.imageUrl)
            builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(bitmap)
                        .bigLargeIcon(null)
                )

        } else {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.app_icon)
            builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        }

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notify(Date().time.toInt(), builder.build())
        }
    }
}
```

here is the create channel part in java after checking

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
}
```

here is your code

```
public void addNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createNotificationChannel();
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.CHANNEL_ID))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("TEST!!")
            .setContentText("TEST!");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, wit.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.CHANNEL_ID), name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but how do I get that piece in my code if I can ask, it would be really great if you want to help with that and thank you very much! And my code is java

Comment: hi 
 check the android version and then create notification channel if you need to 
then you create you notification as usual 
then
I'll update the code with creating channel in java

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification
also don't forget to add your channel id in the notification manger 
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

Comment: Thank you very much in advance, but I just don't understand how I get that in my code, I don't know if you can / want to help with this? If so, I would really like that of you because I have been dealing with this for a while now and cannot get it fixed.

Comment: I've added you your code with the added parts 
i don't know if your are new at this but I've explained the steps 
also i've sent you the tutorial link because you should understand how the code works and the flow
good luck

Comment: What I get now is 'cannot find symbol variable CHANNEL_ID' and this also for 'channel_name' and 'channel_description' and 'CHANNEL_ID' again how can I solve this?

Comment: add it in you strings file